# How can I set the spaces between nodes differently in ggsankey?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sankey-diagram

I have a Sankey diagram built using ggsankey and I'd like to have the spaces of the nodes differ based on their x position (e.g., if they're on the left-hand side, I want the space to be a, and if they're on the right-hand side, I'd like it to be b).

I'm using an initial code to set the size of the spaces based on the number of nodes and the total height I'd like (which is based on the dataset; I have no problems with the values this is outputting). Essentially (forgive me if this isn't the best example):

```
library(ggsankey)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c('left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right'),
               node = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd'),
               next_x = c('right', NA, 'right', NA, 'right', NA),
               next_node = c('b', NA, 'c', NA, 'd', NA),
               value = c(5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2)
)

space.left = sum(unique(df$value)/length(unique(df$x == 'left')-1
space.right = sum(unique(df$value)/length(unique(df$x == 'right')-1
space = 10

plot <- df |>
  ggplot(
    aes(
    x = x 
    ,next_x = next_x
    ,node = node
    ,next_node = next_node
    ,fill = factor(node)
    ,label = node
    ,value = value)
)+
    geom_alluvial(
      inherit.aes = TRUE
      ,mapping = NULL
      ,position = "identity"
      ,flow.alpha = 1
      ,na.rm = TRUE
      ,show.legend = FALSE
      ,smooth = 10
      ,width = .1
      ,color = "transparent"
      ,node.color = "darkgray"
      ,space = space)
```

I've tried (with both 'x' and 'df$x'
`, space = ifelse(df$x == 'left', space.left, space.right)`
`, space = case_when(x == 'left' ~ space.left, x == 'right' ~ space.right)`
with just an 'if' statement, and going into the layer data to apply the spaces when x < 1.5

In most cases, I've been getting these errors:
Warning: Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation:
Warning in geom_sankey(mapping = mapping, data = data, position = position,  :
Ignoring unknown parameters: ``

Any help would be appreciated!